# iPhone UISearchBar animated to top

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

There are lots of apps where the searchbar moves upwards if active and moves down when it is inactive. There is a sample code from apple available which works with IB, but how can I achieve this behavior programmatically? Mostly it is combined with a navigationbar which moves out of the screen in replace with the searchbar

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I ended up using `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` when the search begins and then just do `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` once the search is done.

Answer (score 1):

When the search bar becomes first responder it will animate itself. You can call [searchBar becomeFirstResponder]; or something like that, checkpoint the docs.